# PHP: undefined variable in for-loop

Tags: php, undefined

I am new to php and am trying to write a script that takes a time stamps in the form of "January 23, 2014 at 11:01PM" and breaks them into an array of month, date, year, hour, and minute. Here is my code so far:

```
        $raw_data= array("January 20, 1993 at 10:20PM", "September 6, 1991 at 6:23PM");
        var_dump($raw_data);
        $num_dates= count($raw_data);

//Step 1: break content into month, day, year, hour, and minutes
    for ($i=0; $i==($num_dates-1); $i++) {  
        $partial_data = implode(preg_split("/[A-Z]{2}/", $raw_data[$i])); 
        $broken_data[$i] = preg_split("/[\s,:]/", $partial_data);        
        unset($broken_data[$i][2]);
        unset($broken_data[$i][3]);
    }

    var_dump($broken_data);
```

The code seems to run fine without the var_dump, but when I add it php tells me that $broken_data is an undefined variable.  Anyone see an obvious rookie mistake I'm making?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did obtain any knowledge from your previous question? I do not think so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26308756/formatting-php-for-loop/26308823

Comment: you have unset all the elements of array maybe. So at the end the array is totally unset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your loop condition to use comparison, not equality.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < ($num_dates - 1); $i++)
```

The code inside your loop is never executed because the loop condition fails on the first try.

Comment: Oooo! I learned to code in MatLab where the for loop is denoted from i=__ to i=__. I thought I was telling the loop to go from zero until (num_dates-1).  Thanks!